# Getting conversion values from the new Facebook Pixel

Tags: facebook, conversion, ecommerce-tracking

I'm looking at running some Facebook Ad Campaigns and wanted to install the new Facebook Pixel onto my Magento website.

I'm in Marketing so my coding skills are limited, I normally setup tags in Google Tag Manager for scripts such as this, however from what I can tell, it looks as though to capture events such as (Add to Cart, Successful Sales) I'd have to add in some custom code to the Pixel script and possibly in my Magento code.

Before I get into doing this I just wondered if there are any extensions or easier/ non coding ways to pull in the ecommerce conversion data (Transaction amounts)?

Answer (score 1):

If your need is only to embed facebook pixel. I think you can use the extension below.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-tracking-pixel-and-conversion-code.html

That could be an option for non-coding ways :)

Comment: I think that's for the old Facebook Pixel solution. It shows that it was last updated in June.